# phonegap 3 accessing console log output without xcode

Tags: cordova, console.log

When running a phonegap project in the iOS simulator via the command line:

```
phonegap run ios
```

Is there a way to see the `console.log` output in the command line Terminal?

Note: This question is for the latest phonegap version as of this time (version 3). Some similar questions exist on SO but they are for older version of phonegap.

Comment: Is the tag `cordove` a mistake?

Comment: Don't know if it was, but it is now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help but in Android you can use the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) to debug system output;

```
adb logcat
```